# yml - multiple keys mapping to the same value

Tags: java, configuration, yaml, dropwizard, jersey-client

Java class pulling from the yml config:

```
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
public class myConfig extends Configuration {
  private String name;
  private boolean isActive;
}
```

`my-config.yml` file:

```
myConfig:
  1:
    name: "Customer Cancellation"
    isActive: true
  2:
    name: "Customer Cancellation"
    isActive: true
  3:
    name: "Customer Cancellation"
    isActive: true
```

Can I use:

```
myConfig:
  [1,2,3]:
    name: "Customer Cancellation"
    isActive: true
```

?

The yaml config looks fine but I am not sure if my Java code can pull the information in this format.

Comment: These two YAML files are both valid, but their **meaning** is **different**. The first map contain 3 keys, each of them is *simple* one and mapped to the same value). The second map contains a **single key**, which is a *sequence* of 3 numbers; and this complex key is mapped to a (single) value. So it is not clear what do you mean by "Java code can pull the information in this format." - according to YAML specification a data, which can be represented by the first file, cannot be represented by the second file.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad practice to have multiple keys with same value in configuration. The configuration file mentioned above points to the fact that 1 = 2 = 3.

In my honest opinion, you should use same key in place of 1, 2 & 3.